# Is a classic ASP application a security vulnerability for our environment?

Tags: security, web, asp-classic

If so, in what ways?

Is ASP still maintained for security vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic ASP is part of IIS, so as long as your environment is running on a supported IIS/OS version it would be covered by patches from Microsoft.

> Active Server Pages (ASP) enables web servers to dynamically generate webpages and create interactive web applications by using server-side scripting technology. The use of ASP pages with Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) is currently supported in all supported versions of IIS.
>
> IIS is included in Windows operating systems, and therefore both ASP and IIS support lifetimes are tied to the support lifecycle of the host operating system.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2669020/active-server-pages-asp-support-in-windows

A Classic ASP application can contain security vulnerabilities that can open up the environment to security risks, but these would be flaws in the application and not Classic ASP/IIS.